# Nginx with multiple zend projects

Tags: zend-framework, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm setting up a nginx+php web server for local development with zend framework on Windows. 
I usually just create a new folder in the www root for each project and then create a conf file to project rewrites.

The error here is that I can't access to my static content. When I try to open an image file or css i got a 500 error. And i also dont thing my project conf is 100% correct.. :\

Can you guys help me?

These are my conf files:

fastcgi.conf

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    upstream php {
        server       localhost:8993;
        server       localhost:8994;
        server       localhost:8995;
        server       localhost:8996;
        server       localhost:8997;
        }

    server {
        listen       *;
        server_name_in_redirect  off;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            root   www;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   404              /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           www;
            try_files      $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   php;
            include        fastcgi.conf;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }

        include sites/*.conf;
    }
}
```

example project conf

```
location /zproject {
    root www/zproject;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /zproject/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

**----- UPDATE (request from commment)**

from access.log

> 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jul/2012:11:15:46 +0100] "GET /zproject/content/files/packs.png HTTP/1.1" 404 43648
>   `"http://localhost/zproject"` "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57
>   Safari/536.11"

from error.log

> 2012/07/31 11:15:46 [error] 53696#53724: *5 CreateFile()
>   "D:\webserver/html/zproject/content/files/packs.png" failed (3: The system
>   cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request:
>   "GET /zproject/content/files/packs.png HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost",
>   referrer: `"http://localhost/zproject"`

as far as i can see, it seems he is looking for the files in the wrong location.
The correct location for packs.png is: "D:\webserver/www/zproject/content/files/packs.png" and not "D:\webserver/html/...."

Comment: do you have anything your nginx error logs?

Comment: @JamesButler updated with logs in main question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just needed to add: root "D:\webserver\www"; to the main server configuration. Everything seems to be working as intended :)